# when must I create object?

Tags: java, class, object, oop

I have one class for display with "print" method

```
public class View {
    public View() {

    }
    public void print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

and class with logic, for example, where I will use View class object

```
public class Logic {
    public Logic() {

    }
}
```

when must I create object: in constructor or in method, which wil use this object?

```
public class Logic {
  private View view;
     public Logic() {
        view = new View():
     }
     public someMethod(String string){
        view.print(string);
     }
}
```

or

```
public class Logic {
         public Logic() {
         }
         public someMethod(String string){
            View view = new View();
            view.print(string);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Why are these objects? Does a "logic" contain a "view"? Are either of them encapsulating *any* real-world concept? If they're just containers for code, then you should be using static methods and not allocating any objects in the first place. The "throw everything in an object that does nothing" mindset is outdated and only taught by instructors who learned to program in the 90s and never learned any more recent materials.

Comment: Consider pass View in Logic by constructor parameter.

Comment: Well, you need to create an object if you want to call a non-static method. Whether you create the object in the constructor and reuse it or create it in the method is up to you and depends on other factors. In your case that `print()` wouldn't even have to be an instance method so for that specific method no instance should be necessary at all (of course the method would then have to be static).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second choice because it is more convenient for me, and would shorten it like this: `new View().print(string);`. But if you want to use this object that you created in other classes, then the first choice will be better (using a getter).

Comment: thank you! good idea to use this object using getter